# Google Cloud Pub/Sub psq on AppEngine Flexible Environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create an application is composed of different services that user both the AppEngine Standard (SE) and Flexible environments (FE).

Thus, I need to have a service that runs on SE and enqueues tasks to Pub/Sub topic (topic A). Then, the worker, that needs to run on FE, needs to pull the tasks, make some calculations and enqueue the results to a different Pub/Sub topic (topic B).

Finally, another worker that runs on SE will pull the tasks from topic B and continue its work.

In the documentation of psq, found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psq), it mentions:

> The worker and the applications queuing tasks must share exactly the
>   same source code.

How is it possible to have the functionality that enqueues the tasks with the functionality that consumes the tasks in different environments, if it is necessary to share exactly the same code?